# Email Tracking - Distinguishing Between Book Mark and Email Click Through

Tags: php, email, tracking, thunderbird

If I add a link in an email with query variables such as...

```
http://www.mywebpage.com/?email=person@email.com&page_visited=some_id
```

to help me track email 'click-throughs' and monitor who is accessing my site via the email campaign I started, is there a way to distinguish an actual click with mouse cursor vs someone bookmarking the page after having clicked through once, and just simply accessing the page again via the browser bookmark.

So I need to monitor whether someone clicked through or are accessing the page again via bookmark.

Answer (score 3):

When a user visits your site via an email link, redirect them to another page with a different URL. That way, the bookmarked version will not be the same as the emailed version.

Example:

Email link:

```
http://www.mywebpage.com/?email=person@email.com&page_visited=some_id
```

forwards the user to:

```
http://www.mywebpage.com/?page_visited=some_id
```

and this is the page that gets bookmarked. Now you can distinguish between the types of visits by filtering on the 'email' parameter.